# Xamarin app not deploying even though there is no error in the project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

my Application is showing Error message while i run the project.

[image]

It starts deploying and stops with this message.

I Started the Service of Hyper V and also re - installed Xamarin.Forms as initially it was showing such errors. Solving that i got this Issue.

Please help if any one knows the solution.

Comment: Have you enabled Hyper-V on your computer? How did you create your Android simulator? And what is your simulator architecture? x86 or arm?

Comment: Yes It is Enabled still Not working. @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: Then how did you create your Android simulator? Creating a simulator by using [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sg%2F) or Android Emulator Manager?

Comment: By using VS Emulator for Android @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: Has your simulator been started? And could you please share a more complete error message?

Comment: this is the only message shown in `output` window in VS and And at times it popups with the message i mentioned about deployment errors in comment to @Devesh 's answer. It starts and stop all of sudden with message i displayed in my question. and Nothing Else or any error is shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162307/discussion-between-york-shen-msft-and-divya).

Comment: Have you solved  your probelm?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Tool -> Android -> Android ADB Command prompt

and run this command

```
        adb devices
```

to check if there is connected devices or not. You can restart the adb server from

> Tool -> Android -> Adb Server Restart

Comment: It worked for once and again showed a popup - There are deployment errors, you want to continue? 

And in Output Window it shows 0 Errors.

Comment: @Divya there are deployment error means either apk file did not build correctly or device got disconnected. That is something difficult to guess :)

Comment: There are no errors in apk and build is showing zero errors. I guess its issue with device.

Comment: Check the output window sometime there you can see the log if there is any error

Comment: I've attached  the image in question of Output Window only :|. It is showing these two lines and nothing else than that.